# How to use winjs SplitViewCommand

Tags: winjs

Trying to get started with a simple app using WinJS 4.3 and SplitView. I am following the sample in the winjs playground which is fine but it's lacking the information required to change the content area. I don't see any documentation for SplitViewCommand although I've seen various failed attempts at using it (via searching). So I'd like to have a multi page app (or a single page app that loads in the requested page). What power does SplitViewCommand have? Can I just point it at something like pages/page2/page2.html or do I have to use WinJS.Navigation.navigate(). I'm missing the glue between the command and the content area. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging (I guess winjs is still quite new) I found the answer on the [codefoster website](http://codefoster.com/win8pagenav/). In a nutshell, you can use the PageControlNavigator as your contenthost and use WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/page2/page2.html") as the trigger to change the page.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [WinJS Playground](http://try.buildwinjs.com/playground/). You basically need to have your `contentHost` in the content area of the SplitViewPanel. The, when you "navigate" to a new page, you just render that page on you `contentHost` div.

```
    <div class="splitView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitView">
        <!-- Pane area -->
        <div>
            <div class="header">
                <button
                    class="win-splitviewpanetoggle"
                    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewPaneToggle"
                    data-win-options="{ splitView: select('.splitView') }"
                ></button>
                <div class="title">SplitView Pane area</div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-commands">
                <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Home', icon: 'home'}"></div>
                <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Favorite', icon: 'favorite'}"></div>
                <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Settings', icon: 'settings'}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Content area -->
        <div id="contentHost" class="contenttext"><h2 class="win-h2">SplitView Content area</h2> 
        <!-- this is where pages are rendered -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit: Take a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452768.aspx) on how to navigate. SplitView is no difference than with no control at all. You just need to handle the [WinJS.Navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229778.aspx) events

Comment: Hi, yeah I get that. The information I'm missing is the glue between the example on the WinJS playground (what you have shown here) and the rendering. In other words, is there a property on the SplitViewCommand I can set, like 'location' which will do all the work for me or do I have to set an onclick handler on the SplitViewCommand and then do something with the innerHtml of contentHost? Just not sure how to do the page switching part of the puzzle. Thanks.

Comment: I see, edited my answer with the right links. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that's useful information and something that I haven't found previously, although the codefoster website link provided below is more succinct. Cheers.